# Замена текста с копированием PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли сделать такое - есть например текст со строками:
aaaa 11111 bbbb
aaaa 22222 bbbb
aaaa 33333 bbbb
aaaa 44444 bbbb
aaaa 55555 bbbb
нужно чтобы получилось так:
aaaa 11111 (11111) bbbb
aaaa 22222 (22222) bbbb
aaaa 33333 (33333) bbbb
aaaa 44444 (44444) bbbb
aaaa 55555 (55555) bbbb
Чтобы часть значения каждой строки как бы копировалось рядом с добавлением символов - скобок. Как сделать такое?

Comment: Это можно с помощью регулярных выражений реализовать, конкретно - с помощью preg_replace()

Comment: Я знаю как с помощью preg_replace() заменить, но как в каждой строке получить нужный кусок в переменную для замены?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для поиска с подстановкой используются подмаски *(теги `<pre>` добавлены для визуального форматирования, их можно удалить)*:

```
$str = 'aaaa 11111 bbbb
aaaa 22222 bbbb
aaaa 33333 bbbb
aaaa 44444 bbbb
aaaa 55555 bbbb';

echo '<pre>';
echo preg_replace('~\d+~', '$0 ($0)', $str);
echo '</pre>';
```

Результат:

```
aaaa 11111 (11111) bbbb
aaaa 22222 (22222) bbbb
aaaa 33333 (33333) bbbb
aaaa 44444 (44444) bbbb
aaaa 55555 (55555) bbbb
```

Comment: Спасибо! работает именно так как нужно